# Search SQL Database with multiple string

Tags: mysql, qsqldatabase

I have table like

```
column1       column2      column3
  red         circle         0
  red          line          1
 green        circle         1
 green        circle         0
```

What  I need is search the database with multiple input string, where as I am not aware of column name,

Suppose if the input is like,

Input1:

```
green,circle
```

Result1:

```
 green        circle         1
 green        circle         0
```

Input2:

```
0,circle
```

Result2:

```
  red         circle         0
 green        circle         0
```

Input3:

```
1
```

Result3:

```
  red          line          1
 green        circle         1
```

So basically I need to search the table with multiple combination column items, where as I am not aware of column name. What could be the easiest way?.First I need to find the correct SQL statement to achieve above and then implement in qtsql.

Comment: at least `input3` is ambiguous, since the number can not be differentiated from the `0` number in `input2`. "`input`" should have a more parseable syntax, i.e. `input3 = ",,1"`

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how complex is your work, but I would suggest Elastic search for doing the search with unknown column names.